# Autoload psr-4 with composer

Tags: php, composer, autoload

Прошу помощи, т.к. сам уже кажется всё перепробовал.

Задача казалось бы простая: автозагрузка файлов и классов с использованием autoload composer. До этого пользовался самописным файлом для этих целей, но после внедрения composer, было решено использовать его возможности для этих целей.

И так, ближе к делу:

> composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Cms\\App\\": "App/src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "helpers.php"
        ]
    }
```

Файлы лежат по пути App/src

К примеру, ошибка с первым же созданием объекта класса Router:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cms\App\Router' not found

```
<?php

namespace Cms\App;

class Router
{
```

Файл index.php который лежит в корне:

```
<?php
namespace Cms\App;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$router = new Router();
```

Варианты?

Comment: зачем индексному файлу прописываете `namespace Cms\App;` ? И, у вас же в файле `composer.json` это не всё содержимое, так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил.
Вызвана была моей невнимательностью:
Класс Router находился вне папки src, чего я не разглядел в PHPStorm

[image: Будьте внимательны, друзья!]